# How to check the domain name then go back using history.back();

Tags: javascript, html, api, history

I have a custom button on the page to go to the previous page(using history.back()). But I want to check - when the user click on the button will open my page or something else.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score -2):

```
function goBack(){
        if (document.referrer.includes(window.location.hostname)){
            history.back();
        }
    }
```